# is this a subquery or just an inner join

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, inner-join, correlated-subquery

I am studying the subquery concept, below is one query which is extracted from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery

```
SELECT employees.employee_number, employees.name
   FROM employees INNER JOIN
     (SELECT department, AVG(salary) AS department_average
       FROM employees
       GROUP BY department) AS temp ON employees.department = temp.department
   WHERE employees.salary > temp.department_average;
```

the sql is a rewritten version of an correlated subquery as below

```
 SELECT
   employee_number,
   name,
   (SELECT AVG(salary) 
      FROM employees
      WHERE department = emp.department) AS department_average
   FROM employees AS emp;
```

And now my question :
Is the sql from the rewritten version a subquery? I am so confused on it

```
  INNER JOIN
         (SELECT department, AVG(salary) AS department_average
           FROM employees
           GROUP BY department) AS temp ON employees.department = temp.department
       WHERE employees.salary > temp.department_average;
```

Comment: Both queries shown here have subqueries. The first one is a correlated subquery.

Comment: If you want a specific term, subqueries in the FROM clause (including JOINs) are sometimes referred to as **inline views**.

Comment: To clarify, the one with an INNER JOIN is *not* a correlated subquery since the subquery doesn't reference the outer query at all - it relates to the outer query via JOIN conditions instead.

Comment: @kfinity I would change "sometimes referred to" to "properly referred to", since "inline view" is what they are called in the Oracle SQL Reference Guide.

Comment: Hi  @kfinity, Not quitely understand the ' (including JOINs) are sometimes referred to as inline views.'  when a subquery happened in the from clause, is there any other sample except JOIN?

Comment: Sure, a subquery can be the only "table" in your FROM clause. But I just wanted to clarify that the JOIN clause is part of the FROM clause in case it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is certainly confusing, so I'd make it a little bit simpler by using two different tables and no table aliases.

I'd say if it's in the `FROM` clause, it's called a join:

```
SELECT employee_id, department_name
  FROM employees JOIN departments USING (department_id);
```

If it's in the `WHERE` clause, it's called a subquery:

```
SELECT employee_id
  FROM employees
 WHERE employee_id = (
         SELECT manager_id
           FROM departments
          WHERE employees.employee_id = departments.manager_id);
```

If it's in the `SELECT` clause, it's called a *scalar* subquery (thanks, @Matthew McPeak):

```
SELECT employee_id,
       (SELECT department_name
          FROM departments
         WHERE departments.department_id = employees.department_id)
  FROM employees;
```

Comment: A subquery is an entire select in parentheses. It doesn't matter where it is. If it is a 1-column 1-row result converted to the value inside it then it is a scalar subquery. A join is 2 tables joined by keyword JOIN or comma in a FROM, each given by a base table name or subquery or parenthesized nested join or a preceding join. This is straightforward. This post is unclear & wrong. "if it's in the FROM clause, it's called a join"--No. "If it's in the WHERE clause, it's called a subquery"--No. "If it's in the SELECT clause, it's called a scalar subquery"--No. (Though what "it" is unclear.)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly.  The equivalent would be a `left join`.  The correlated version keeps all rows in the `employees` table, even when there is no match.  The `inner join` requires that there be a match.

In general, the execution plans are not going to be exactly the same, because the SQL engine does not know before-hand if all rows match.

With the additional filtering condition, the two versions are equivalent.  Note that the filter for the correlated version requires a subquery or CTE because the `where` clause does not recognize column aliases.